# Antivirus algorithm in DataStructure

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, antivirus

I want to make a Antivirus Software in Data Structure using C#. So help needed for the Algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You can find algorithms here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/clamav/

The code is writted for unix but as you are interested in algorithm only so it will work for you. It's a popular antivirus for UNIX called "Clam Antivirus".